# Ergodic theorem with more conserved quantities

Tags: conservation-laws, equilibrium, phase-space, complex-systems, ergodicity

Ergodic theory is constructed by fixing the dynamics on a surface of the phase space with constant energy. In case a non-integrable system conserved more additional quantities apart from the energy, is it possible to construct a 'generalized ergodic theory' on the lower-dimensional hyper-surface of the phase space which, accounting for the additional conservation laws, is still metrically indecomposible w.r.t. dynamics?

Any reference where such topic is discussed would be also really appreciated.